# Creating sub-list from list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am having trouble understanding a concept in prolog.

I have a prolog list:

`MyList = [item(dog,red), item(cat,black), item(rat,gray)]`

and I am looking to create a list of just the colors i.e.
`[red,black,gray]`

Currently the solution I have tried is:

```
getlistcolors([item(_,C)|T], Result) :-
    getlistcolors(T,Result),
    append([C],Result,Result).

getlistcolors([],_).
```

I would like to be able to call the function:

```
?- getlistcolors(MyList, Result).
Result = [red,black,gray]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `setof(Color, member(item(_, Color), MyList), ColorList).` will give the unique, sorted list of colors. If you want literally the colors, including any duplicates, `findall(Color, member(item(_, Color), MyList), ColorList).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
getlistcolors([], []).

getlistcolors([item(_,C)|T], [C | Result]) :-
    getlistcolors(T,Result).
```

You can't append the new find `C` color with

```
append([C],Result,Result)
```

because you're imposign that the second list and the appended list are equals.

You should use two different variables writing

```
getlistcolors([item(_,C)|T], Result) :-
    getlistcolors(T,HeadC),
    append([C],HeadC,Result).
```

but you can obtain the prepend-`C` effect simply translating `C` as head of the second argument

```
getlistcolors([item(_,C)|T], [C | Result]) :-
```

Second point wrong with your code: the terminal clause can't be written as

```
getlistcolors([], _).
```

or the second argument isn't unified with `[]` and the reasult become something like

```
[red,black,gray|_20]
```

where `_20` is a variable that isn't unified.

Comment: Thanks @Maxx66. How does this actually work? I understand the that the function is recalled, but with `every item but the current item (Tail)` and the empty `Result list` , plus the closing clause `getlistcolors([], []).`, but don't understand how the `[C | Result]` run's and works as the function is exiting.

Comment: @DeanMeehan - the `[C | Result]` works exactly as `[item(_,C)|T]` works. `getlistcolors/2` is called to the closing clause (`([],[])`) that set the base of the result (the empty list), next the result is enriched with every `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to fix a problem in lurker comment:

when using setof/3 or bagof/3, you have to specify 'universal quantification' of each variable involved in the query, you're not interested in:

```
?- MyList = [item(dog,red), item(cat,black), item(rat,gray)],setof(Color, P^member(item(P, Color), MyList), ColorList).
MyList = [item(dog, red), item(cat, black), item(rat, gray)],
ColorList = [black, gray, red].
```

the missing quantification problem is better explained in the bagof section of [inline documentation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)

A SWI-Prolog solution could make use of libraries yall and apply (both autoloaded, you don't have to worry about including them):

```
getlistcolors(List, Colors) :- maplist([E,C]>>(E = item(_,C)), List, Colors).

?- getlistcolors([item(dog,red), item(cat,black), item(rat,gray)],Cs).
Cs = [red, black, gray].
```